# How do I make an a-frame entity aware that its animation attribute has changed?

Tags: animation, aframe

I have an `<a-box>` in **aframe** with an `<a-animation>`:

```
<a-box scale='3 3 3' position='0 3 -8' color=red>
  <a-animation begin=move attribute=position dur=2000 to='10 3 -12'></a-animation>
</a-box>
```

If I set the `to` attribute to a new value and then run the animation, it executes the animation using its previous `from` and `to` values.

However, if I remove the `<a-animation>` from the **dom** and then add it again (with the new `to` value set), it will now animate using the new value.

Is there a way to set the new `to` value and then make the the `<a-box>` / `<a-animation>` aware that its `to` value has been updated so that the next time I emit the `begin` `move`, it will use the new `to` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This animation component should recreate the animation configuration every time any property changes: https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/animation . I will be maintaining this animation implementation more than the `<a-animation>` one that may become deprecated.

```
<a-box scale='3 3 3' position='0 3 -8' color='red'
       animation__move="startEvents: move; property: position; dur: 2000; to: 10 3 -12"></a-box>

document.querySelector('a-box').setAttribute('animation__move', 'to', '20 20 20');
```